# How to convert timedelta64[ns] object -1 days +23:40:00 to -20?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

'2019-07-29 10:00:00' - '2019-07-29 10:20:00' = -1 days +23:40:00

I want to get just minute.

```
diff = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2019-07-29 10:00:00', '2019-07-30 10:30:00'])) - pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2019-07-29 10:20:00', '2019-07-30 10:15:00']))
print(diff)
print(diff.dt.components)

0   -1 days +23:40:00
1            00:15:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
   days  hours  minutes  seconds  milliseconds  microseconds  nanoseconds
0    -1     23       40        0             0             0            0
1     0      0       15        0             0             0            0
```

I want to covert like this,

```
print(diff)
0   -20
1    15
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(diff.dt.components)
df['new'] = df['minutes'] + 60 * df['hours'] + 1440 * df['days']
print(df['new'])
```